# Fixed/sticky sidebar with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Уже много гуглил, но так и не смог найти ответа для себя, где-то работает, где-то - нет. Не могу понять как сочетаются ***position: fixed*** и ***display: flex***. Некоторые говорят обернуть, но не получается в этом примере. 
Так вот, моя проблема: хочу сделать как в [этом](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity) примере, только через ***flexbox***. Оно должно работать по идее и без [этого](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prop_element_offsettop_sticky) (другой) примера, но я добавил его уже от безысходности. Контент  по идее должен отодвигаться, а ***sidebar*** всплывать при нажатии на ***OPEN***. Но когда я задаю ***position:fixed*** контент даже не отображается.
Остальные вопросы: 
1.) Есть ли смысл ***sidebar*** вообще делать на ***flexbox***?
2.) Так как я только начинаю писать на JS, то можно ли как-то в JS коде, в ***stickyFunction()***, третья строка, указать: if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky && **function openNav() РАБОТАЕТ** (укажите код как это написать))[![

```js
var x = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
  if (x.style.display == "none" && x.style.width == "0") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
    x.style.width = "250px";
  }
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}



function stickyFunction() {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky && (x.style.display != "none")) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: .5s;
  width: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sidenav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="stickyFunction()">
  <!-- скролл -->
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a> /* закрытие */
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- обёртка, для того, чтобы контент отодвигался -->
    <!-- это не важно -->
    <header class="header">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#" class="hrefs" id="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="hrefs">News</a>
        <a href="#" class="hrefs">Contacts</a>
        <a href="#" class="hrefs">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="iconMenu()">&#9776;</a>
      </div>
    </header>

    </br>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    <!-- открытие -->
```

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNkXK.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNkXK.png)

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать подобный эффект, пробуем вот так:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open')
}); 

$(".menu").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
  $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: #EFF9F0;  
  font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
   
}

h3 {
  color: #747474;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3:after {
  display: block;  
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #FE5D26;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1D1A31;
  width: 0;
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  transition: cubic-bezier(.88,.22,0,.9) 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 24px;
}

nav a:before {
display: inline-block;
content: "";
height: 2px;
width: 1px;
background: #fff;
flex: 1;
margin-right: 5px;
}

nav a:hover:before {
display: block;
height: 24px;
transition: 300ms;
}

.nav-open {
width: 300px;
transform: translate(0);
transition: cubic-bezier(.88,.22,0,.9) 0.3s;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
}

.wrapper {
margin: auto;

}

article {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.fitured-image {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6B4D57;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(http://pexetothemes.com/demos/story_wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2947294095_992a7fd836_o-copy1.jpg) ;
 
}

.fitured-image-caption  {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
bottom: 30%;
}

.fitured-image-caption p {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: .9;
}
.fitured-image-caption li {
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 2px
}

.fitured-image-caption li:nth-of-type(2) {
border-top: 2px solid #FE5D26;
padding: -12px;
font-size: 42px;
}

.fitured-image img {
width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.menu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu.open .menu-item {
  background: #fff;
}
.menu.open .menu-item:first-child {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform-origin: 10px 50%;
}
.menu.open .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu.open .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform-origin: 8px 50%;
}

.menu-item {
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <span class="menu-item"></span>
  <span class="menu-item"></span>
  <span class="menu-item"></span>
</div>

<nav>
  <a href="#close">Option 1</a>
  <a href="#close">Option 2</a>  
  <a href="#close">Option 3</a>  
  <a href="#close">Option 4</a>  
  <a href="#close">Option 5</a>  
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">  

    <div class="fitured-image">
      <ul class="fitured-image-caption ">
        <li>
          <p>About me
            <li>The developer
      </ul>
     </div>

      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. 
      </article>

      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Это концепция, чтобы понять саму разметку. После понимания какой контейнер в чем находится, будет проще реализовать.

Comment: У меня уже получилось сделать по-своему, но вот что я заметил, то у Вас такая же проблема как и у меня. Выполните код, и тогда скрольте, слева Вы увидите, что там есть текст белый. Прокрутите и остановитесь на чёрном чём-то. 
у меня с этим были проблемы, пока не поставил display: none, а при клике чтобы flex ставало. Но желаемого результата я так и не добился, оно не выходит плавно, как я и хотел